# How to restore a backup and incremental backup of scyllaDB

Tags: performance, replication, backup, restore, scylladb

I am working on incremental backup and restore. When I am trying to restore the incremental backup, after restoration, I am getting an error on cqlsh shell.

> ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed for example_keyspace.users - received 0 responses and 1 failures from 1 CL=ONE." info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}